# Xcode & Android Radio Scanner

Tags: iphone, android, xcode

Hi im still not 100% with xcode and android. I have the Droid X and I code with Xcode. My dad is on the Fire Dept. and wants me to code an app for either the android and/or iphone that detects the dispatch's radio signal and receives it and streams it in the background so the firemen could listen to the radio on their phones so they wouldn't have to carry their bulky radios with them everywhere. If there is someone that could help me or point me in the right direction, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you, Halokllr

Comment: XCode is Apple's IDE for dealing with iPhone/iOS development. Its not geared for Android. What are you actually using, and what have you tried? Your problem is a multi-pronged one involving audio capture, internet radio re-broadcasting, servers, client applications, etc. I would try to tackle something simpler.

Comment: If the dispatch radio is broadcast over the **internet**, then you can create an application to play that audio.

Comment: Yann: I know that Xcode isn't geared for Android.  I'm using Google App Inventor for Android dev. I've seen (and I have) apps for police scanners on my Droid.  What I was wanting to know is how they made the app, and if it was possible to recreate something like it for iPhones or how to make it with Google App Inventor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some bad news Halokllr, the iPhone doesn't have a radio chip, and the FM radio included in some Android models will probably not be able to physically pick up emergency broadcast signals.  In order to do what you are suggesting, you would need a web service of some kind that already exists and streams audio for the emergency signals you're interested in.  Now there ARE some services like this, though I would strongly suggest that if it is intended to be used for actual first responders that you very carefully research their timeliness guarantees.  Some of them may be hours behind live events.  Check out http://www.radioreference.com/ as an example service provider.